# mvn package to build one jar with multiple assemblies

Tags: java, maven, package

I want to build one jar to include 3 assemblies. 
The purpose is to run the jar in shell with specific main class.

```
java -jar Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar FirstMain
java -jar Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar SecondMain
```

However, the following pom.xml configuration builds three jars, the default
jar is not runnable with error "Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute".
How can I fix this to run all three main with single jar file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.my.test</groupId>
<artifactId>TheTest</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Test</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <defaultGoal>compile</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-firstmain</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.my.test.main.FirstMain</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-FirstMain</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-secondmain</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.my.test.main.SecondMain</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-SecondMain</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-appmain</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.my.test.main.ThirdMain</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-ThirdMain</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Open the third jar and check in the Manifest file if the "Main-Class" attribute is there.

Comment: no, there is only the manifest file for third jar.

Answer (score 0):

When I want a single jar from which I can execute any of several main classes, I include only one maven assembly execution, with one of the main classes specified.  When I want to execute that main class, I execute the jar normally, for example:

```
java -jar Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

When I want to execute one of the other main classes, I designate the jar as the classpath and specify the class I want to execute on the command line.  For example:

```
java -cp Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.my.test.main.SecondMain
```

Note the use of `-cp` instead of `-jar`.

Comment: thanks , but it seems there is no manifest in the jar. I cannot run these command.